# Why is filter method not deleting all elements of the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
this.arol.filter(x=>x.length!==0
                ?(this.arol.splice(this.arol.indexOf(x),1))
                :!true)
```

I was trying to change it many different ways, but it still does not delete all elements of the array, it always leaves 1 or 2 behind deleting most of them.... I think the problem is with the condition... We are checking if the length of array elements is not 0 (which are all strings)...

Comment: `!true`? Allow me to introduce my friend `false`.

Comment: Never use `splice` during an iteration. Why are you not just using `arol = arol.filter(…)`?

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to `splice` *while* `filter`ing - instead, return from the `filter` callback a truthy or falsey value, depending on whether you want to include the item being iterated over in the new array, and use the resulting array that gets returned from `.filter`:

```
this.arol = this.arol.filter(x => x.length !== 0);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain same outer array reference and mutate original you *can* splice in a loop if you work from end to start so as not to affect indexing you haven't arrived at yet as you change the array length:

```js
const arr = [[1],[],[2]]
arr.reduceRight((_,c,i) => c.length || !!arr.splice(i,1))

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to splice at the same time you are using filter. Filter does not remove elements from your array, it creates a new array with the filtered data, as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

You can assign the result to the same array as suggested by CertainPerformance.

Answer (score 0):

If Splice is removed from that code then it will not delete elements. `this.arol.splice(this.arol.indexOf(x),1)` here it will iterate through every element inside that array and `x` will be current iteration which will splice from the array as you have written splice method. Remove `splice` it will work fine.